# Access elements in a 3D List

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
[['EWR', 2, 3], ['Queens', 0, 5], ['Brooklyn', 1, 1] ]
```

How would I extract the 0 if I have the string Queens in a var?

In other words how would i express: I want the first int in the list that starts with the word Queens.

EDIT: Queens (and strings in general) is always in first position. The list structure can't change

Comment: What if there are 2 `Queens`?

Comment: There isn't. It is a list that contains all of NY districts

Comment: A dictionary might be the better datastructure for this.

Comment: Namedtuple would be good for this. Create the structure and iterate through building a list, then you can do all sorts of logic with the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you could use the following [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). If you're interested in the first integer, simply index the sublist to select the second value when the first string is `'Queens'`:

```
l = [['EWR', 2, 3], ['Queens', 0, 5], ['Brooklyn', 1, 1] ]
[i[1] for i in l if i[0] == 'Queens']
# [0]
```

Comment: True but its not a dynamical answer

Comment: From the example it seems that the string is always in the first position, and the rest are ints. If that were not the case, IMO OP would have chosen a better example contemplating other scenarios

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: thak you. This seems to work on the console but when I try all the script I have something like: [D[1] for i in D if i[0] == temp][0][1] I get the error The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I mean the string 'Queens' may not be always 1. index . Given spesific index works just this example @yatu

Comment: @wawa can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This works fine for your case. Also please clarify whether or not 'Queens'  can be in other positions or always in the first

Comment: Queens (and strings in general) is always in first position. The list structure can't change

Comment: Okay. Note that the code you've share is different than the answer I've posted. PLease check again @wawa

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly *first int* and you're not sure what index it's gonna be you could this as follow using list comprehension and python builtin [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function. Because we are taking advantage of using `generators` instead of `lists` in out list comprehension we'll always stop iterating after finding first occurrence of whether the first `int` value or final sentence with first value `Queens`.

```
x = next(next(filter(lambda x:isinstance(x, int), i)) for i in my_list if i[0] == 'Queens')
print(x) # -> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just bruteforce it, ill make an example easy to understand:

```
def find_in_3d(input, your_list):
    for second_layer in your_list:
            if input in second_layer:
                return second_layer[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list, and check the condition if Queens is present in the list, then append the second element in output list

```
lst = [['EWR', 2, 3], ['Queens', 0, 5], ['Brooklyn', 1, 1] ]

ext_list = []
for l in lst:
    if 'Queens' in l:
        ext_list.append(l[1])
print(ext_list)
#[0]
```